# What does the Emotion CSS macro do, and how do I use it?

Tags: javascript, css, emotion, css-in-js

In Emotion v10 the docs say "There is a Babel macro available for css from @emotion/core if you import it from @emotion/css/macro though." This is apparently available for users who don't have the ability to change their babel configs.

Assuming you're not using the JSX pragma or babel plugin, what is the point of this macro, and how do you use it?

In a fresh `create-react-app` app, I can `import css from '@emotion/css/macro';`, and even use the `css` tagged template, but it's not obvious what I'm supposed to do with its return value (an object with a `name` and style text). Without the pragma or plugin I don't have access to the `css={}` prop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be useful in a fresh `create-react-app`  only when using the `jsx` pragma (and the `jsx` named import from `@emotion/core`.

Source: [Emotion's `css prop` docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#babel-preset)

```js
/** @jsx jsx */

import { jsx } from "@emotion/core";
import css from "@emotion/css/macro";

export function Home() {
  return (
    <div
      css={css`
        max-width: 1080px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      `}
    >
      <p>the css macro only works with the JSX pragma</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the vanilla `emotion` `css` export and apply the return value to the `className` prop:

```js
import React from "react";
import { css } from "emotion";

export function Home() {
  return (
    <div
      className={css`
        max-width: 1080px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      `}
    >
      <p>hello new page</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```